# spree extension entering facebook app id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've got the extension spree_social_products installed in my spree 2.4.7 store on rails 4.1.8 and everything is working great except I cannot get the facebook intergration to configure.

The extension is here: https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_social_products

I have an issue when trying to set my facebook app id.

The readme says run up a rails console and enter

```
Spree::Social::Config.facebook_app_id = 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID'
```

When I run that command in the console I'm getting the following.

```
`<main>'2.1.0 :011 > Spree::Social::Config.facebook_app_id = 'XXXXX123456'`


NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::Social from (irb):11 from 

/home/mspree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@spree2.4/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:instart'
....
```

I running the command correctly ?
I've tried rails console and rails console development, both give the same error.

Comment: Have you `bundle`d recently?

Comment: I believe so as the other parts of the extension are working ,google+ pinterest , twitter. I'll double check though -thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out  I had the wrong namespace and I had to create and set the value. I was expecting the variable to be present but it was not.

I found the following helpful.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/Giuh5avHuRo